# What font is this Sans Serif (AUTOTEAMPENO logo)?

Tags: font-identification

I tried all the existing web services to be able to identify the character used in the logo.
I tried as well to optimize the picture as said by all the web services, like WhatTheFont, etc.
I tried literally all the sources I could, but sadly I couldn't find none like the font used. The font for the logo is different by the one used in the website itself (RobotRegular). Tried to compare, with no luck as well..

The Logo was not done by me, was provided by a sponsor, the original WebDeveloper is unreachable.

I'm not paid and part of a non-profit organization which is now dealing with all the related stuff. In this specific case I had to provide the logo in vector form to an external company which will provide us the soccer team equipment (shirts, etc)

The logo is coming from [their own site](http://www.autoteampeno.ch/). I took it from there as they didn't have any other media.

[image: Logo]

Comment: It looks like somebody's made a modified a mid-period Citroen Logo - https://www.citroen.co.uk/about-citroen/citroen-inspired-by-you [scroll down] - possibly by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Champagne & Limousines Thick Bold

A retro Sans Serif font, inspired by the sans serif from 1930.

Link at [fonts2u.com](https://es.fonts2u.com/champagne-limousines-thick-bold.fuente?ptext=NUOVO%20%26%20USATO&size=1)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: WoW, thanks!!!!
How did you manage to recognize the font? based on your experience or have you used some service? If yes, which one?